# c# outlook MailItem add/remove recipient of type BCC

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

I want to programmatically add with C# recipients to an existing/composing MailItem. When I add a recipient like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = inspector.CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient mRecipient = item.Recipients.Add("test.user");

mRecipient.Type = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
```

it appears in the TO field of the MailItem.

[image]

When I do something like this:

```
item.BCC = "test.user";
```

it appears correclty...

[image]

Is there a way to to add the recipient with the first method (Type.olBCC) and show it up in the BCC mail field (2nd snippet)?
I want to go this way because then I can iterate through all recipients and remove some when a special condition is called.

The problem is when I remove the added BCC recipient with

```
item.BCC = "";
```

all recpients were deleted in the BCC field.

Comment: It does seem that outlook only provides a list for the To option, not cc or bcc.

Comment: You could use LIST<string> bccEmails {"test.user"}; item.BCC = String.join(), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently we are all missing the point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-object-outlook

According to this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient mRecipient = item.Recipients.Add("test.user");
mRecipient..Type = olCC   // at a guess here olBCC would be BCC...
```

We can modify the list as a list.. :)

Note: I couldnt find olCC in my list.. but maybe I need to look harder.

Note2! Found it.

OlMailRecipientType. has olTo, olOriginator, olCC and olBCC

There you go.  so `mRecipient.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olBCC` should do the trick

The following - opened a new mail item with joe.bloggs in bcc:

```
    olApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    m = olApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    Recipient r = m.Recipients.Add("joe.bloggs");
    r.Type = (int)OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
    m.Display(true);
```

Having saved a draft and worked out how to get hold of it as 1 item apparently isnt items[0] ..

the following also works:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folderDrafts = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
    if (folderDrafts.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        m = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)folderDrafts.Items[1];
        Recipient r = m.Recipients.Add("joe.bloggs");
        r.Type = (int)OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
        m.Display(true);
    }
```

Comment: mRecipient.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olBCC  -> is the same that I posted in my question!

Comment: Hmm well it moves it to bcc for me.. so..something else must be wrong. I did             m = olApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Recipient r = m.Recipients.Add("joe.bloggs");
            r.Type = (int)OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
            m.Display(true);  and got the mail window open with bcc...

Comment: But yes, I missed it in your code cos clearly it hadnt worked.

Comment: I think it does work with a CreateItem(MailItem) object. In my scenario I get the current MailItem object with the Inspector. Then the recipient will appear in the TO field..

Comment: Then you havent provided a minimal viable example... its hard for me to replicate that

Comment: OK found that - nope something in your code you havent shared is wrong as mine works.

Comment: What is "Globals"?

Comment: Globals is the Context to the AddIn when I work in the RibbonCS code module.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of needed info missing.. and you're making a lot of work for me, while it feels you arent doing any...  the short answer is, it is displaying wrong but it knows better.. if you add anything else after, the thing moves to the right location. its the last one you add will stick in the "to" until something else is added.  so if you add a second one, the first moves to the right place, and remove the second one that first remains in the right place

Comment: It is okay, stop searching! I just wonder why it is not shown up correctly in the right way when I use a current MailItem. Maybe it is a timing-thing. It works with CreateItem -> the Recipients are open to receive. Current Item it seems Recipients are closed. Thank you anyway for help.

Comment: Well Ive given you a work around - add another one, and then remove the extra.. it then leaves it in the right place

Answer (score 0):

As the user BugFinder mentioned there is a workaround neccessary since the UI adds the BCC recipient to the olTO field. I solved this with first adding a dummy, then add the BCC and remove the dummy:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = inspector.CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;

//Create dummy recipient object for UI bug
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient dummy = 
 item.Recipients.Add("bugDummy");
 dummy.Type = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
 //Create the BCC object that will be used
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient mRecipient = item.Recipients.Add("test@user.de");
 mRecipient.Type = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
//iterate through the recipients and delete the dummy
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipient in item.Recipients)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(recipient.Name, "bugDummy", true) == 0)
                    {
                        recipient.Delete();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```